# Does the CXF Rest Client use connection pooling?

Tags: java, rest, cxf, cxfrs, cxf-client

When I google, I see [evidence](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/HTTP-Connection-Pooling-td561783.html) that the CXF Rest Client uses connection pooling by default, but I'm not sure how to prove that.  My sources are very old and I can't tell if it applies to cxfrs or just the web services.  I can't tell if it's using `HttpUrlConnection`, HttpConduit, or Apache HttpComponents.  Etc.

This is my maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Does the CXF Rest Client use connection pooling by default?  If so, is there a way to adjust the settings?

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from [their mailing list](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Does-the-CXF-Rest-Client-use-connection-pooling-td5754816.html):

> Hi Daniel,  As far as I can see from my sources for 3.0.1 and which
>   may not have change  much, cxf jax-rs client configuration uses
>   HTTPConduit which in turn uses  HTTP urlConnection for normal client
>   and http commons client for async  client.
>
> So connection pooling if any might be at JVM level and not at cxf
>   level for  urlConnection.
>
> Regards,
>
> Ulhas Bhole

Depending on how you're using it, you can research HTTPUrlConnection or HTTPConduit and figure out how to configure them for thread pooling.